# play() not working when changing HTML <video> source in mobile

Tags: html, html5-video, plyr.js

I am trying to change the src attribute of an HTML < video > element and play it after 10 seconds of playing the first video, in desktop it works fine, however, in mobile devices it gets stuck after changing the source and it never plays.

I am using plyr.js, however the same happens without it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  const player = new Plyr('#player', {
      controls: ['play-large', 'play', 'progress', 'current-time', 'mute', 'volume', 'captions', 'settings', 'pip', 'airplay', 'fullscreen'],
  });

  player.on('ready', event => {
    player.play();
  });

  player.on('timeupdate', event => {
    console.log(player.currentTime);
    if (player.currentTime > 10) {
      player.source = { 
        type: 'video',
        sources: [
          {
            src: 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4',
            size: 720,
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I am aware of webkit  policies however, they don't specify that after changing the source the video need user interaction again to be played, it doesn't make sense to me.

https://codepen.io/andreupifarre/full/qJYeJL/

Is this part of the policy? Am I doing something wrong? Can this be done?

Comment: if you set the video to muted (and follow other requirements for auto-play without interaction) does it work?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal If I set the video attribute to muted, the video plays and works correctly.